# Differentiation proof

Tags: derivatives

Find the co-ordinates of the point on a curve $y=x^2+3x-1$ at which it is parallel to the line $ y=5x-1?$

unsure how to solve this

Comment: Which line do you want to find that is parallel to the line $y=5x-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want tangent line of the $y=x^2+3x-1$ to be parallel to $y=5x-1$, solution is:

Find derivative of the first line
$$y=x^2+3x-1 \Rightarrow y'=2x+3.$$
For the lines to be parallel, their derivatives have to be the same
$$y=5x-1 \Rightarrow y'=5$$
$$2x+3=5 \Rightarrow x=1.$$
We can find the coordinates if we plug the $x=1$ into our first line
$$y=1+3-1=3.$$
Coordinates are $(1,3)$